# Data at the root level is invalid, line 1 level 1

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently attempting to parse a byte array by converting it into an XML string and loading a DOM over it. My code can be seen below:

```
public static List<Purchase> ParsePurchases(Profile profile, byte[] data)
{
    // Parse the profile XML and extract purchases
    // read the data into a string
    var xmlString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

    // create the DOM over it
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

    // parse it
    var purchaseElements = doc.GetElementsByTagName("purchase");
    List<Purchase> purchases = new List<Purchase>();

    for(var e = 0; e < purchaseElements.Count; e++)
    {
        var ele = (XmlElement)purchaseElements[e];

        try
        {
            purchases.Add(
                new Purchase(
                    profile,
                    Int32.Parse(ele.GetAttribute("id")),
                    Int32.Parse(((XmlElement)ele.GetElementsByTagName("price")[0]).InnerText),
                    Int32.Parse(((XmlElement)ele.GetElementsByTagName("quantity")[0]).InnerText),
                        ((XmlElement)ele.GetElementsByTagName("description")[0]).InnerText
                    ));
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Var ele is null");
        }
    }
    return purchases;
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that this code is throwing an error:

> "Data at the root level is invalid, Line 1, position 1".

Here is a sample XML doc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<profile username="215">
    <purchases>
        <purchase id="6271">
            <price>728</price>
            <quantity>14</quantity>
            <description>Sample</description>
        </purchase>
    </purchases>
</profile>
```

Comment: At which line is the error thrown? Do you have an example of the XML and/or byte array you're providing?

Comment: The error is being thrown in my doc.GetElementsByTagName call. I'll go and retrieve an XML now @Equalsk

Comment: I recently had a similar issue with the same exception and, to sum it up, there were problems with the BOM in a XML-File I read from. Could the BOM be a problem for you also?